# How to save a Word 2016 doc as a PDF without the creation of another page that's filled with all the document specs?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

Really strange. This Word 2016 version doesn't allow me to "Save as" as PDF. It only gives me the option to "Export". And when selected, the newly created PDF has an extra added page filled with document details such as:

> ```
> Filename: Pathway - Accomodations List NOV2017.docx
> Folder: /Users/AL/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents
> Template: /Users/AL/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T39.Office/User
> Content.localized/Templates.localized/Normal.dotm
> Title:
> Subject:
> Author: AL
> Keywords:
> Comments:
> ```

etc, etc…

So what was a one-page pdf is now a 2-page pdf. How to make it disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "Print to PDF" instead of "Save to PDF". WYSIWYG.

A few of these options are discussed here: https://www.howtogeek.com/150891/how-to-print-to-pdf-in-windows-4-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that I needed to select the save as for web option, not the print for paper option. Jeez. Took me forever!